# Trouble creating fog and lighting in unity

Tags: unity, lighting, skybox, sky

I am trying to create a model in unity that looks like this picture by Escher [image: link]

I can create the lattice, however, I can not create the fog and background/lighting effect. When I adjust the fog in Lighting the cubes just get more of the supposed fog color. Also I don't know how to eliminate the sky and make the lighting more like it is in the picture. Does anybody know how to great the fog and lighting effect I am looking for Thanks 
I previously posted this on unity Q and A and got no answer

[image: Image with fog colored white]

I can not post my other image with no fog because i do not have enough reputations. It is basically the image I posted just with more shadow and gray cubes.

Comment: Can you share some examples of what you've done so far, and why you're not happy with it? It's not clear what you mean by "more gray" but not "really" a fog effect.

Comment: The cubes become more like the color of the supposed fog. I will add examples soon.

Comment: I think it would look a lot better if you draw a skybox that's the same color as the fog

Comment: how do I even make fog skyboxses

Comment: This still looks to me like what you want. All you need to do is set the camera's clear colour to white to get rid of the harsh edge where cubes meet blue. If that still doesn't create the look you want then you'll need to give us more explanation of how it differs from what you're trying to do.